# Why java.util.UUID is Comparable?

Tags: java, uuid, comparable

UUID in java implements Comparable. Which seems a bit weird to me, since, in almost all cases UUIDs are randomly generated (or deserialized from somewhere but still they were probably originally randomly generated).

There doesn't seem to be any sense comparing them, unless you generate them manually with sequentially incremented LSB/MSB, which might make sense if you just want a very big ID number (two longs instead of one plain long), but that's the only explanation I can think of.

Comment: What about using them as a real ID in an entity? Just as you'd compare 2 longs seeing if an entity is "bigger" than another the same can be done with UUIDs

Comment: yeah, that's the explanation i wrote in the post, it will only work if you manually generate UUIDs with incremented lsb/msb. but that is not a main use case for UUID

Comment: A UUID incorporates a Date doesn't it?  You can compare based on that.  Is that the behavior?

Comment: Suppose you read 2 values [from string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#fromString-java.lang.String-) and you need to check them for equality (maybe in some complex json objects or smth similar)?

Comment: nope, a uuid is just two longs making up a very big number, has nothing to do with date

Comment: @Morfic that's equals() not compare

Comment: Are you sure?  V1 and V2 both encode date: [Version 1 (date-time and MAC address)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address))

Comment: Looking at the [IETF RFC 4211](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt), there is a section about the lexical order of `UUID`s: "***Rules for Lexical Equivalence**: Consider each field of the UUID to be an unsigned integer as shown in the table in section Section 4.1.2.  Then, to compare a pair of UUIDs, arithmetically compare the corresponding fields from each UUID in order of significance and according to their data type. Two UUIDs are equal if and only if all the corresponding fields are equal.*"

Comment: @Turing85 right, but still, in the common use case of UUID, doesnt make sense to compare them, only check if they are equal. I don't need to know if a uuid is 'bigger' or 'smaller' than another uuid. even though they are numbers essentially

Comment: @paranoidAndroid that is how the RFC defines it. I see nothing wrong in the implementation realizing the defined order. Whether and how it is used is up to the user.

Comment: @paranoidAndroid "I don't need to know if a uuid is 'bigger' or 'smaller' than another uuid" then don't call `compareTo`. Just because you don't want to, doesn't mean others don't, especially if the standard in which UUIDs are declared says they should be comparable.

Comment: @AndyTurner right, i dont use it :) but it's just interesting why the JDK developers chose to implement a compare method for something that is rarely compared this way

Comment: @paranoidAndroid "rarely" is a very subjective term. *You* don't, (I don't), others might.

Comment: @paranoidAndroid again, because the RFC defines it. To be compatible with the RFC, one should define the defined order.

Comment: @Turing85 I can accept this reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some UUID versions have meaning encoded into their values:

> There are four different basic types of UUIDs: time-based, DCE
>   security, name-based, and randomly generated UUIDs.

Because of this it can make sense to compare UUID since you can derive meaning from their values.  You could loosely say "This UUID was made earlier or later" than another.

Consider the versions defined on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)):

- Version 1 (date-time and MAC address)
- Version 2 (date-time and MAC address, DCE security version)
- Versions 3 and 5 (namespace name-based)
- Version 4 (random)

You can even see this in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html):

> The layout of a variant 2 (Leach-Salz) UUID is as follows: The most
>   significant long consists of the following unsigned fields:

```
 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 time_low
 0x00000000FFFF0000 time_mid
 0x000000000000F000 version
 0x0000000000000FFF time_hi
```

See [How is a Time-based UUID / GUID made](https://www.famkruithof.net/guid-uuid-timebased.html)

Comment: Good to know this. I marked as an answer. Thanks

Comment: While it's true that "You could loosely say "This UUID was made earlier or later" than another", the order defined by RFC and by the `Comparable` implementation doesn't, and this layout is exactly why. Or you need a quite loose definition of "loosely" :) `time_mid` rolls over and makes order different from temporal order every `0xffffffff * 100 nanoseconds = 7.15827883 minutes`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov to be totally honest, I’m not sure how confident in this answer I am. It seemed like the OP wanted a concrete reason why you could compare UUID and the fact that they could hypothetically be “date sorted” seemed appropriate. I don’t know that I agree with it being the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: As Turing85 noted in the comments (and later in a [full-fledged answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51031470/2422776))), Java's [`java.util.UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class implements [RFC 4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). This RFC clearly defines an order, so it makes sense for this class to implement such ordering - i.e., by implementing `Comparable`.

Regardless of that, even if sorting does not serve any "business" logic, it has a lot of other advantages.

First, it allows you to be consistent. A system that behaves deterministically, where X always comes before Y is easier to maintain, debug, and arguably use.

Second, sorting is extremely helpful in avoiding deadlocks. If you always update entities (and take the locks required to do so) in the same order, you eliminate a lot of pitfalls where X is waiting for Y's lock, which itself is waiting for X's lock.

And finally - why not make UUID comparable? The added byte code for implementing `compareTo` increases the class' size by a negligible size. If you don't use it as a `Comparable` you'd hardly suffer from it, and making it implement `Comparable` gives the class' user the added flexibility to use it as such.

Comment: you wouldn't make your ID number comparable, right? From my point of view, it is pretty much the same

Comment: @Turing85 that's a good point - edited into my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the [Javadoc of `UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), we see that it references [IETF RFC 4122: A Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) URN Namespace](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). Within mentioned RFC, we find a section concerned with lexical equivalence:

> ```
> Rules for Lexical Equivalence:
>    Consider each field of the UUID to be an unsigned integer as shown
>    in the table in section Section 4.1.2.  Then, to compare a pair of
>    UUIDs, arithmetically compare the corresponding fields from each
>    UUID in order of significance and according to their data type.
>    Two UUIDs are equal if and only if all the corresponding fields
>    are equal.
>
>    [...]
>
>    UUIDs, as defined in this document, can also be ordered
>    lexicographically.  For a pair of UUIDs, the first one follows the
>    second if the most significant field in which the UUIDs differ is
>    greater for the first UUID.  The second precedes the first if the
>    most significant field in which the UUIDs differ is greater for
>    the second UUID.
> ```

This means: in order to fully implement mentioned RFC, one needs to implement the defined order. The way to implement this in Java is by either `implements Comparable<...>` or by providing a `Comparator<...>`. Since the order defined in the RFC is the "natural order" of `UUID`s, it is only logical to let `UUID implements Comparable<UUID>`.

As to how this order can be used or if it even should be used is not up for debate. My argument is solely based on the implementation of the standard. Whether and how to use this order is up to the user. [Mureinik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51031298/4216641) and [Alexey Romanov's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51031288/4216641) answers give some reasons as to why one would want to have an order defined without explicitly exploiting it.

---

Adendum

If one upvotes my answer, one should upvote [Alexey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51031288/4216641) aswell. My answer was written later, but follows the same line of argumentation. Furthermore, Alexey provides an example on how this order might be useful.

Comment: "none of the answers so far seem to have picked up this comment" Mine did, actually :) That's what "more relevant" refers to, since this paragraph by itself only defines how `equals` should behave.

Comment: Huh, funny. Sorry, somehow I did not pick that up. The first part of my answer, however, is obsolete anyway (and I have already edited it out) since Mureinik picked up on my comment aswell.

Answer (score 5):

This is required e.g. to put them into a `TreeMap`/`TreeSet`. The more relevant quotes from the RFC are

> UUIDs are of a fixed size (128 bits) which is reasonably small
>      compared to other alternatives.  This lends itself well to sorting,
>      ordering, and hashing of all sorts, storing in databases, simple
>      allocation, and ease of programming in general.
>
> UUIDs, as defined in this document, can also be ordered
>         lexicographically.  For a pair of UUIDs, the first one follows the
>         second if the most significant field in which the UUIDs differ is
>         greater for the first UUID.  The second precedes the first if the
>         most significant field in which the UUIDs differ is greater for
>         the second UUID.

Comment: It's not required to be `Comparable`, there could be a `Comparator<UUID>` declared somewhere.

Comment: yeah, this is a nice reason but still, i don't think it makes either sense to put a UUID as a key in a tree, since why would i want to sort it by uuid..

Comment: Because hashmaps aren't always a fastest way to find something, and faster ways often involve sorted data structures (`TreeMap` is just used as an example of one). A sorted array with binary search, a B+-tree (often used in databases), etc.

Comment: It also has advantages when used as keys in a `HashMap`: ["Note that using many keys with the same hashCode() is a sure way to slow down performance of any hash table. To ameliorate impact, when keys are Comparable, this class may use comparison order among keys to help break ties."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) Although hash collisions should usually not be too frequent for UUIDs because their hashcode-implementation does produce a reasonable distribution, there are A LOT more possible UUIDs than the "Integer.MAX_VALUE" hashes

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense if you use it i.e. as an id.

Or if it's necessary to keep objects in tree-like data structures.